# db_update with a hook

Tags: hooks

Have a field called url_time in the users table.
I have this function in place, though it does not update the table on the else part.

Does this code look correct?

```
function my_module_form_submit($form,$form_state)
{
global $user;
$account = user_load($user->uid);
$op = $form_state['values']['op'];

if ($op == $form['linkedin']['reset']['#value']) {
    if (db_field_exists('users', 'url_time')) {
        db_update('users')
            ->condition('uid', $account->uid)
            ->expression('url_time', 0)
            ->execute();
    }
}
else {
    $date = time();
    if (db_field_exists('users', 'url_time')) {
        db_update('users')
            ->condition('uid', $account->uid)
            ->expression('url_time', $date)
            ->execute();
    }
}
}
```

This is the linkedin function that I am trying to implement, so when the user authorities, the "else" will write a date.

```
function linkedin_user_enable_form($form, $form_state, $uid) {
$form = array();
$form['#user'] = $uid;
$form['#action'] = url('linkedin/token/' . $uid);
$form['submit'] = array(
 '#type' => 'submit',
 '#value' => t('Go to LinkedIn'),
'#suffix' => '<p class="description">' . t('You will be taken to the LinkedIn website in order to complete the process.') . '</p>',
);
return $form;
}
```

Comment: You cannot delete just a database column; you can delete one or more database rows.

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't delete just the field, it would delete the row for a user whose `uid` equals `$account->uid`. The `->expression()` and subsequent `->execute()` as @kiamlaluno points out, wouldn't work right anyway.

If you want to simply delete the value, you are better off doing something like this:

```
// $account is defined up ^^ there somewhere.
$account->url_time = '';
user_save($account);
```

Comment: Actually, the second is not a condition, so it doesn't catch those rows where url_time is 0. Plus, the object returned from `db_delete()` doesn't have any `expression()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong: To set the value of *url_time* for the user row matching a user ID, you need to use the `UpdateQuery::fields()` method.

> Adds a set of field->value pairs to be updated.

The correct code is the following one.

```
if (db_field_exists('users', 'url_time')) {
  db_update('users')
    ->condition('uid', $account->uid)
    ->fields(array('url_time', 0))
    ->execute();
}
```

This is similar to the following code used by Drupal core, which updates *expire* for the records matching the conditions.

```
  // Insure that the timeout is at least 1 ms.
  $timeout = max($timeout, 0.001);
  $expire = microtime(TRUE) + $timeout;
  if (isset($locks[$name])) {
    // Try to extend the expiration of a lock we already acquired.
    $success = (bool) db_update('semaphore')
      ->fields(array('expire' => $expire))
      ->condition('name', $name)
      ->condition('value', _lock_id())
      ->execute();
    if (!$success) {
      // The lock was broken.
      unset($locks[$name]);
    }
    return $success;
  }
```

Comment: If this helps clear things up a little. I want to delete the data inside the field. The default value I set for the field is 0. So I want to use the if (db_field_exists but want the url_time to be reset to the default value in the long run.

Comment: So, do you just need to set url_time to 0 for the user for the given user ID?

Comment: I change my original post.

Comment: For the future, remind you cannot change a question once it has answers in a way to invalidate the answers. Before posting a question be sure you are describing exactly what you need to do. _Deleting a database column_ is different from _updating a database column_.